# PLSQL - How to replicate a row changing columns first characters?

Tags: sql, plsql, substr, replicate

I have a table with products like this:

```
PRODUCT_ID    SUB_PRODUCT_ID    DESCRIPTION   CLASS
----------    --------------    -----------   -----
A001        ACC1                coffeemaker   A
A002        ACC1                toaster       A
A003        ACC2                coffee table  A
A004        ACC5                couch         A
```

I need to replicate a row changing only first characters in some columns to get a result like this in the same table, for example if I take the first row I want to copy `PRODUCT_ID` changing only the first letter (from A001 to B001), `SUB_PRODUCT_ID` changing only the first letter (from ACC1 to BCC1), keep `DESCRIPTION` and change `CLASS` (from A to B)

```
PRODUCT_ID    SUB_PRODUCT_ID    DESCRIPTION   CLASS
----------    --------------    -----------   -----
A001          ACC1              coffeemaker   A
B001          BCC1              coffeemaker   B
```

I have been trying using SUBSTR function without positive results.

Comment: Please share your attempts with `SUBSTR`

Comment: From the table with desired output it looks like you'd like to have both rows with original values AND modified. Is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
insert into products(PRODUCT_ID, SUB_PRODUCT_ID, DESCRIPTION, CLASS)
    select replace(product_id, 'A', 'B'),
           replace(SUB_PRODUCT_ID, 'A', 'B'),
           DESCRIPTION,
           replace(CLASS, 'A', 'B')
    from products
    where class = 'A';
```

EDIT:

`replace()` might be overkill:

```
insert into products(PRODUCT_ID, SUB_PRODUCT_ID, DESCRIPTION, CLASS)
    select 'B' || substr(product_id, 2),
           'B' || substr(SUB_PRODUCT_ID, 2),
           DESCRIPTION,
           'B'
    from products
    where class = 'A';
```

Comment: Thanks! Gordon! Your edited answer works for this situation!. The clause 'where class = 'A' was an extra help I needed to! Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called "products" and you want to change all rows ( or add a constraint as needed):

```
insert into products
select 'B'||substr(product_id,2), 'B'||substr(sub_product_id,2), description, 'B'
from product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi You can do a lilte bit of code twisting and here's the output :)

SELECT 'A001' PID,'ACC1'SPID,'cofeemaker' dsc,'A' clss FROM dual
UNION
SELECT REPLACE(a.pid,SUBSTR(a.pid,1,1),'B') PID,
  REPLACE(a.SPID,SUBSTR(a.spid,1,1),'B')SPID,
  a.dsc,
  REPLACE(a.clss,SUBSTR(a.CLSS,1,1),'B') CLSS
FROM
  (SELECT 'A001' PID,'ACC1'SPID,'cofeemaker' dsc,'A' clss FROM dual
  )a;
```